# How to remove the header row of spark RDD in most efficient way?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Here is the sample the dataframe that I have. Btw, this kind of question is asked by some companies as a puzzle question to test understanding of Spark dataframes. So instead of suggesting ideal ways of avoiding this problem, better come up with ideas to do it most efificiently.

```
val full_csv = sc.parallelize(Array(
  "col_1, col_2, col_3",
  "1, ABDFGHC, XYZ",
  "2, ADASDFA, LOM",
  "3, WERWRE, BCT"))
```

Comment: seems duplicate to me https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45316810/how-to-delete-the-first-few-rows-in-dataframe-scala-ssark

Comment: Sounds like you are reading a csv, why don't you use appropriate methods for that. `spark.read.options("header", true).csv("path")`

Comment: try this full_csv.collect.drop(1) hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

```
path = "/path/*.gz"
data = sc.textFile(path)
header = data.first()
data = data.filter(lambda row: row != header) # filter out the header
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing an answer. Would you kindly edit your answer to to include an explanation of your code? That will help future readers better understand what is going on, and especially those members of the community who are new to the language and struggling to understand the concepts.